# undefined delay of pixel data from image sensor

Tags: video

Would it be possible for MCUs to capture valid pixel data from Sony's IMX225LQR-C image sensor? On page 49 of this [datasheet](http://astroccd.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/IMX225LQR-C_E_TechnicalDatasheet_Rev0.2.pdf) it's written that the sensor generates sync codes to distinguish between invalid pixel data and valid pixel data. When Vsync and Hsync signals are given, then processor needs to wait for specific SAV(Start of Active Video) values in the pixel data pins(D0~D11). After identifying the specific 12-bits values, your processor should capture the pixel data until it receives EAV(End of Active Video) values. The pixel clock is 74.25Mhz, which is quite high. Then would it be possible for MCUs in general or for Atmel's [SAMA5D2](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-11267-32-bit-Cortex-A5-Microcontroller-SAMA5D2_Datasheet.pdf) to capture video from this image sensor?

Comment: Anything is certainly possible.

Comment: I would say that an ARM Cortex-A5 running at up to 500MHz, as your link says, especially with DMA, you wouldn't be lacking in terms of specification, but depending on your PCB design/layout skills and your software experience, it would be better described as "possible but not easy". @Andyaka - have you ever tried opening a can of beans with a banana?

Comment: I wanted to ask if the image sensor controllers in MCUs are capable of detecting the SAV, EAV signals (with undefined delays) and capturing valid data. Could you please clarify what the limiting factor is? I would like to assume that PCB design is good enough. I'm wondering if I need FPGA instead of MCU(or MPU)

Comment: @Andyaka I think a MCU like STM32F429 can't make it. Its digital camera interface(DCMI) has two synchronisation methods. But I think one can't take image from this sensor with the hardware/embedded synchronization. This is the link. You can check the section 15.5.3 http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/3d/6d/5a/66/b4/99/40/d4/DM00031020.pdf/files/DM00031020.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00031020.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that CPU includes a "ITU-R BT. 601/656/1120 Image Sensor Controller" that is capable of interfacing directly with that sensor.

You will be dealing with a parallel bus that is running at 74.25 MHz, which will require some care in the PCB design, but not any more than the 166 MHz external memory bus of the CPU. Probably not a problem for someone used to dealing with 0.4 mm to 0.8 mm pitch BGAs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But does the IMX225 sensor use BT.1120, even it has undefined delay of SAV?

Comment: The "undefined delay" that the sensor specification is referring to is the delay from the sync *input* to the SAV in the output stream. The content of the output stream itself is always self-consistent and the CPU's interface will be able to parse it correctly.

Comment: Thank you again!. But I'm so sorry that I couldn't follow your explanation quickly. 1. Could the SAMA5D2 also capture 1280x960 image? It might not be BT.1120, or? 2. Could I expect that the SAMA5D2 would find out how many 12-bit numbers are output between falling edge of Hsync and SAV?

Comment: 1. Sure. As long as the output stream contains valid SAV/EAV sequences, the CPU should be able to handle it. 2. Maybe. Why is this important?

Comment: 2. I though MPU would not distinguish the invalid data between Hsync and SAV from valid data. Since I don't have experience in image sensor interfaces of MCU/MPU yet, I might misunderstand how the controller capture valid pixel data. I really appreciate for your answers!

Comment: Hsync is just a frame timing (frequency) reference, that allows you to synchronize the sensor with other video signals at the line and frame level. The difference between valid and invalid data is entirely indicated by the SAV and EAV sequences embedded within the output stream.

Comment: Ah...I see. If you don't mind, could I please ask one more question? In the section 49.5.3 and 49.5.4(page 1889~1893) of the following data sheet, http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-11267-32-bit-Cortex-A5-Microcontroller-SAMA5D2_Datasheet.pdf it's written that you could take 10-bit or 8-bit SAV/EAV. But when you would use 12-bit Bayer Raw data or 12-bit Monochromatic data, could you take the SAV/EAV from sensor? I'm sorry for bothering you with lots of questions..

Comment: I don't know. A 2600+ page document is a bit much to take in first thing in the morning. Section 49 seems to hint that you can't use embedded sync in raw mode, but I'm not sure about the details. You'll have to work it out on your own or find someone who has experience with this interface on this CPU.